# Android studio cannont find the file specified (after update)

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Today I updated my android studio from 3.2 to 3.4 but after download it can't build and gives this error :

ERROR: C:\Users\amir.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.1.1-all\97z1ksx6lirer3kbvdnh7jtjg\gradle-5.1.1-all.zip (The system cannot find the file specified)

the gradle downloaded successfully (Download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip 5 m 28 s 617 ms) but has error in sync

Comment: Try to delete the cache,build-cache folder from the C:\Users\.android and sync again.

Comment: @MeetPatel I did it but still does't work

Comment: check your "service directory path" from "File => settings => Build, Execution, Deployment => Gradle => service directory path"

Comment: @android It seems right "C:/Users/amir/.gradle"

Comment: open gradle-wrapper.properties and then copy paste this path distributionUrl=file\:/C:\Users\amir.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.1.1-all\97z1ksx6lirer3kbvdnh7jtjg\gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

Comment: @android It says invalid string escape . I don't know how i should change it

Comment: please add \\ like this "distributionUrl=file\:/C:\\Users\\amir.gradle\\wrapper\\dists\\gradle-5.1.1-all\\97z1ksx6lirer3kbvdnh7jtjg\\gradle-5.1.1-all.zip"

Answer (score 3):

You can update it from:

**File->Settings ->Build, Execution, Deployment-> Gradle-> use local Gradle distribution.**

Then select the path of this file: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip (after downloading)
then hit apply.